# References Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, surfaces

I read on Wikipedia about that the Gauss-Bonnet theorem for compact two-dimensional Riemannian manifolds $M$ with boundary $\partial M$ with Gaussian curvature $K$ of $M$ and geodesic curvature $k_g$ of $\partial M$ states:

$$
\int_M Kd\sigma+\int_{\partial M}k_g ds=2\pi\chi(M)
$$
where $d\sigma$ and $ds$ are volume forms and $\chi(M)$ the Euler characterstic of $M$. Does anyone have a references in which this proven?

Comment: Differential Forms and Applications by Manfredo P. do Carmo

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7834/undergraduate-differential-geometry-texts/7846

Comment: Feel free to download my free [differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). It's proved completely in there (with a second proof, with differential forms, sketched as well).